# Get the parent object property value in child property in Validation Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

This question is related to Asp.net MVC5.
Similar question is answer here[: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674841/net-mvc3-conditionally-validating-property-which-relies-on-parent-object-proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674841/net-mvc3-conditionally-validating-property-which-relies-on-parent-object-proper/)

I have the following View Model:

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public List<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
    //.....
    //.....
}
public class ChildModel
{
    [DateOfBirthRange(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth must be within range")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    //.....
    //.....
}

public class DateOfBirthRange : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return null;
        //here validationContext.ObjectInstance is ChildModel
        //How do i get the Effective Date of ParentModel?
    }
}
```

ChildModel is a list and I need to validate for DateOfBith of all child models w.r.t Effective date value in ParentModel.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET DataAnnotations based validation does not offer recursive validation. However, you could extend it as explained [here](http://www.technofattie.com/2011/10/05/recursive-validation-using-dataannotations.html). Doing so, you gain control over how the `ValidationContext` (used for validating child objects) is created.

So, in the `ValidateObjectAttribute` of the mentioned article, when instantiating the new `ValidationContext` in `IsValid` , instead of passing `null` as a service provider, you could pass a custom `IServiceProvider` that gives you the parent validation context and using its `ObjectInstance` you get the parent object being validated.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could move validation logic to the ParentModel by implementing `IValidatableObject` on it. 
Arguably, your rule does not apply to the ChildModels themselves, but to the the complete Parent object with all its children, as the effective date is a property of the parent object.

```
public class ParentModel : IValidatableObject
{
    //.....
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
        foreach (var child in Children.Where(child => child.DateOfBirth.Date < EffectiveDate.AddYears(-1).Date || child.DateOfBirth.Date > EffectiveDate.Date))
        {
            result.Add(new ValidationResult($"The date of birth {child.DateOfBirth} of child {child.Name} is not between now and a year ago."));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

(assuming a rule for validity of date of birth w.r.t. the effective date, and a name property on ChildModel.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a navigation property in your ChildModel class back to its parent. Then you can do something like the following:

```
public override ValidationResult(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var childModel= validationContext.ObjectInstance as ChildModel;
    var effectiveDate  = childModel.Parent.EffectiveDate;
    // do your tests against effectiveDate and childModel date
}
```

Comment: ChildModel doesn't have a property Parent.I need to no is there any way of getting ParentModel that was ModelBinded on post to server in this ValidationContext.

Comment: Give your ChildModel a navigation property so that it *can* get back to the parent and yes - otherwise how can you expect to find the parent? It should be trivial to give it this property.

Comment: @Mashton Its not trivial to give the child model a navigation property back to the parent model, as how is that navigation property suppposed to be populated from a postback from a form?